# How to display application logs on a windows form?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have a log file which is growing as the task progresses. I want to display the contents of this file (like Linux's 'tail -f') on the form to a component (multiline textbox probably).

I am not looking at windows event logs or AllocConsole.

I want to show the progress of the task submitted by the user through a button on the form, on the form itself.

Comment: You described a task, you did not ask a question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am sorry, which part of the article does my question not adhere to?

Comment: The Internet has many examples on how to do it. First you can search "lmgtfy" and then search what your question is concerning.